# Where to find pre-made wires for plugging into headers?

Tags: connector

Headers like these:

http://uk.farnell.com/harwin/m20-8760342/header-smt-vertical-2x3way/dp/1517388

I'm looking for cables that connect to these, with female headers on either end. Any length more than ~5cm is ideal. But I can't seem to find any results on my favourite websites. I'd rather not spend time crimping them myself as I have to produce a lot of them.

For this application I need 4 way connections, but it would be nice if many different way counts were available, so I know what to buy in future.

Comment: How many wires per cable?

Comment: Good point - I need 4 way. I've edited the question appropriately.

Comment: @ThomasO did you ever find a UK distributor of these?  I've been making them myself by hand, but having trouble with high frequency signals...

Comment: Always find it crazy when someone posts a question which many others are interested in, and others offer useful answers, only to have the topic voted to be closed as being off topic, or some similar complaint. At least these questions can still be searched on google, and will remain useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**4P/F to 1P/F Jumper Wire**

[MDFLY](http://www.mdfly.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=65_69&products_id=74&zenid=035ga7ae4fmop7s4bmpi424h65)

Jumper wire with one 4-pin female connector on one end and four 1-pin female connectors on the other end.

[image: 4P/F to 1P/F Jumper Wire]

**'x'P/F to 'x'P/F Jumper Wire Combination**

[MDFLY](http://www.mdfly.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=65_69&products_id=79&zenid=035ga7ae4fmop7s4bmpi424h65)

Select a jumper wire with 1-pin to 8-pin female connector on each end.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I'm just wondering if these are available from bigger distributors. Also if I can get them in the UK. These are pretty much what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas --

[SparkFun](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9389) sells individual wires with a female connector at both ends, designed to plug into pins spaced 0.1" (2.54 mm) apart.  Wires are 12" (4.75 cm) long.  Sold in packs of 10 or 100.

[Samtec](http://www.samtec.com/ftppub/pdf/hcmd.pdf) has ribbon cables with single-row 0.1" sockets (HCSS series), but only has options for 5, 8, 10, 12 or higher count wires.

Answer (score 1):

Digikey sells something along those lines.  They are flex cables with headers mounted on either end.  Keep in mind that they are pretty pricey versus building your own.

They are on page 74 and 75 of the 2010 catalog:

http://dkc3.digikey.com/PDF/US2010/P0074.pdf

http://dkc3.digikey.com/PDF/US2010/P0075.pdf

Adafruit sells them as well, but only in 6-conductor, 6".

http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=33&products_id=206